# Elongated words and combination of words in a sentence python

Tags: python, for-loop, split, stringstream

I have a few lines such as:
biggestfoolofall, sooo, hiiieee, footballfan

If you notice the pattern above, either there are a combination of words in 1 word itself such as "biggestfoolofall" "footballfan".

1) I wanted to know how I can understand that its a multi-word within 1 words.

2) sooo and hiiieee are elongated words.I want to detect elongated words in python. How can I do that?

I am new to python so got stuck at this part. Also, if you can share any helpful sites to learn for loops, strings split etc then it would be very helpful

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide

Comment: You'd be better off using a dictionary that uses a trie. Words are only words if they are written down. Regex knows nothing of words.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a list of valid words. So iterate over your words and check if they are in your line:

```
for word in words:                              # iterate over all valid words
     if word in line:                           # if a valid word is found in line
         print 'I found a valid word: '+word
         line.replace(word,'')                  # remove the word from your line
```

At the end, you end up with finding all valid words and only junk characters left in your "line" variable.

See [string methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) for further string operations.

Comment: Would be more involved than that because of overlapping cases - e.g. 'fall' in 'foolofall'.